# Automate captcha using webdriver?

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver

How to automate captcha using WebDriver?

Is there any alternate method to automate Captcha using Webdriver?

Comment: You should just turn off the CAPTCHA for the given environment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can automate CAPTCHA only using display CAPTCHA value in "alt" attribute.

1. take `CAPTCHA` image in WebElement
2. get value of `"alt"` attribute
3. pass `alt` value in text field

Comment: I think that it's very optimistic to see the captcha in the "alt" field, because that defeats the purpose of captcha.

Comment: You are right: tester need to tell developer to display value in "Alt" attribute for testing purpose only. After testing is completed we can remove value from alt.

Comment: @bugCracker: nice one. Impressed.

Comment: Out of box answer dude +1 for you.

Comment: Yup Good solution provided by bugCracker. +1 for you.

Comment: @bugCracker can we automate capache of following link

https://www.irctc.co.in/eticketing/loginHome.jsf

Comment: Not possible, If you able to see captcha value in HTML than what is the use of captcha?

Answer (score 0):

`CAPTCHA` and `barcode` are not read/test/handle by Selenium WebDriver.

`Selenium WebDriver` doesn't support CAPTCHA and barcode.

Answer (score 0):

I came across [Death By Captcha](http://www.deathbycaptcha.com/).

They have **good reviews** and also **provides API** to decode image captchas.

It is a ***paid*** service.