# Selenium - Display captcha image in prompt

Tags: selenium, captcha

I am using Selenium to automate testing of a large web form, everything works well and I have managed to display a prompt box which prompts the tester to enter the captcha...

```
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>prompt(&quot;Please enter captcha&quot;)</td>
    <td>captcha</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>id=captcha_answer</td>
    <td>${captcha}</td>
</tr>
```

This works ok but I am looking for a way to display the actual captcha image in this prompt box.  I have the generated image as a URL, is there a way to do this?

Comment: this will help you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18055598/automate-captcha-using-webdriver

Comment: Thanks but not what I asked, I am looking for a way of displaying an image in the prompt

Comment: You are using Selenium IDE?