# By Pass a Captcha using Alt attribute? automation

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, alt

it it possible to use alt to bypass Captcha.. I'm not the developer of the project.. my question is if its possible that the developer can do that?

*i already try it but it doesn't work?
Im testing a registration form using selenium Webdriver java

Comment: i was reading this:
<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18055598/automate-captcha-using-webdriver>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to bypass Captcha, you best bet is to just disable it.  The option you are mentioning is putting the Captcha value in an alt tag, which would work.  However, this would only be practical in a testing environment; otherwise, the whole point of Captcha is bypassed.

This provides some good options:

[how to get the data from captcha in selenium webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18933178/how-to-get-the-data-from-captcha-in-selenium-webdriver)

In short, one of your developers will have to help you bypass Captcha using one of the provided mechanisms in the link above (or using your alt tag method in a testing environment).

Comment: sorry for not completing my info this my first time automate the registration. yes Im on testing environment im planning to use that alt but it didnt work.. yes disabling it is one of my option. cool thanks for the info.