# How to wait to enter data in a text box manually in Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I want to enter the captcha text manually so how to write the code for this?

Here is my code:

```
driver.findElement(By.name("/atg/commerce/order/purchase/CommitOrderFormHandler.userCaptcha")).sendKeys(captcha);
```

I am getting below error :

```
Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with Command duration or timeout: 9 milliseconds Build info: version: '2.41.0', revision: '3192d8a', time: '2014-03-27 17:18:15' System info: host: 'WID1376', ip: '172.21.22.76', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0_35' Session ID: 65dab209-84aa-436a-915f-7a52174405a5 Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver Capabilities [{platform=XP, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, version=23.0, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, handlesAlerts=true, browserConnectionEnabled=true, nativeEvents=false, webStorageEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true}]
```

Comment: Your question is confusing.You're asking to enter captcha text manually and same time using webdriver. Please explain what you want you achieve using WebDriver storing captha or entering some text in captch text field?

Comment: If you want to get captch text, then your question is duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18933178/how-to-get-the-data-from-captcha-in-selenium-webdriver

Comment: Here is also related question http://stackoverflow.com/a/18055667/2504101

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enter the value manually...place an explicit wait (eg: thread.sleep(20000);) and enter the captcha text manually within 20sec. This may help you. If not read the links provided by TDHM and olyv