# How to do dynamic testing by using selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium

I want to write test script for "Captcha" field by using selenium webdriver.

is it possible to test "Captcha" by writing script.if yes then how to use selenium webdriver to test "Captcha" field.

Comment: I think there is no direct way to automate captcha...you should follow this link...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18055598/automate-captcha-using-webdriver

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of a captcha is preventing robots to get through them. Your automated test is a robot, so basically a captcha is designed to stop you from getting past it. There is no proper way to get past one.

If there is a way to get past it you should replace your captcha with a more secure one as it'd mean the only thing your captcha is designed to do is flawed and your application has security issues.